# How do I print something into a discord channel from my json file? - Discord.py

Tags: json, discord, bots, discord.py, channel

How do I print what is in my json file to the discord channel. I have events to post but I want it to show the name of the event in the channel [Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07bAK.png)

Here is my json file with the event names [Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPcas.png)

So, how do I make it look like the first example?

EDIT FOR COMMENT:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCGqz.png)

2ND EDIT FOR COMMENT:
[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGjbO.png)

Answer (score 0):

To work with json, first you would need to `import json`. After that, `json.loads("file.read()")` and store that into a variable.
Then, to send the contents of it, you can:

```
result = ""
for i in range(len(variable["eventstitles"])):
    result += f"{i + 1}. {variable["eventstitles"][i]}"
```

After that, `await ctx.send(result)` or `await channel.send(result)`

Click [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) for more info about grabbing specific channels.

EDIT:

```
with open("events.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    result = ""
for i in range(len(data)):
    result += f"{i + 1}. {data['eventstitles'][i]}\n"
await ctx.send(result)
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is this line right actually by the way?

```
    result += f"{i + 1}. {variable["eventstitles"][i}"
```

Because parts underline red. I changed the 'variable'.

Comment: Oh my bad forgot a ] there. By the way, I don't think this is the best way to do this, it's just the way I know how.

Comment: Wait can you re write that line to what it should be please? I am confused now

Comment: I did, I edited the message. Anyways here it is:
result += f"{i + 1}. {variable["eventstitles"][i]}"

Comment: Please check the edit on the main question as I am still having trouble

Comment: I forgot something in the answer, you need to do json.loads(file.read()) and file needs to be open("name of file", "r"). You also want to send the result after the for loop

Comment: Hey, can you please check the second edit. I am so confused with all thse things you forgot. Can you also edit your answer with the full code I need to add in please?

Comment: Done. Again, I'm sorry for the confusion